# Will precession cause geosynchronous satellites to become non-geosynchronous?

Tags: orbital-motion, space, satellites

Will the precession of Earth cause geosynchronous satellites to eventually become non-geosynchronous? I can't think of any reason why they would follow the changing axis.

And can anything be done about it for the existing satellites?

Comment: For an idealized spherical Earth the answer is that the orbit will retain it's orientation in space while the Earth turns under it. That would render geostationary orbits non-geostationary but wouldn't de-synchronize orbits (the distinction being one of hovering above a fixed point on the surface versus sharing a common period). However, the Earth has non-trivial higher multipole moments meaning that things are not so simple.